# MYSQL - append or insert value into a column depending on whether it's empty or not

Tags: php, mysql, string, concatenation

As title says, im trying to append a `string` to a `VARCHAR` column in my table. 
The string is something like " //string ", forward slashes will be used later to explode the string to an array in PHP. 
I was wondering if there's a way **in MYSQL** to perform a `CONCAT(columnname, "//string")` if the column is empty, otherwise perform a normal `UPDATE ... SET ... WHERE` . In this way, i will avoid ***the first*** value of my future exploded string to be a "//string" with forward slahes.

also, above I 've used **bold** characters for "**in MYSQL**" because I know i could first query the DB (to check if the column is empty) with something like:

```
$q = $conn->dbh->prepare('SELECT columnname FROM tablename WHERE username=:user');
$q->bindParam(':user', $username);
$q->execute();
$check = $q->fetchColumn();
```

and then leave PHP decide which operation perform:

```
if ($check != '') { // PERFORM A CONCAT }
else { // PERFORM AN UPDATE }
```

but this would mean a waste of time/resources due to 2x database calls and more PHP code.

thanks.

Comment: y not both - first apply the update with where condition, then insert where not in

Comment: will the row already exist for the user or not?

Comment: yeah the row already exists for that user.. i said INSERT, but with that i meant an UPDATE tablename SET columnname='//string' WHERE [..and so on..]

Comment: i edited the question to clarify

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html

That means in your case:

```
INSERT INTO tablename (id,columnname) VALUES (1,'//string')
  ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE columnname=CONCAT(columnname,'//string');
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/bd0f4/1

**UPDATE** Just to show you your options:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/8e61c/1

```
INSERT INTO tablename (id, columnname) VALUES (1, '//string')
  ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE columnname=CONCAT(columnname,'//string');

INSERT INTO tablename (id, columnname) VALUES (1, '//string')
  ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE columnname=CONCAT(columnname,'//string');

INSERT INTO tablename (id, columnname) VALUES ((SELECT id FROM tablename t WHERE columnname='blahblah'), '//string')
  ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE columnname=CONCAT(columnname,'//string');

INSERT INTO tablename (id, columnname) VALUES ((SELECT id FROM tablename t WHERE id=2), '//string')
  ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE columnname=CONCAT(columnname,'//string');

INSERT INTO tablename (id, columnname) VALUES ((SELECT id FROM tablename t WHERE columnname='newone'), '//newone')
  ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE columnname=CONCAT(columnname,'//newone');
```

Comment: i cant accept as answer because i can't use UNIQUE in that column. Also, i guess you meant " VALUES('string') " not "VALUES('//string')".. but this is close to my goal..EDIT: i cannot even use WHERE in this statement.

Comment: so give me your `CREATE TABLE` statement. You didn't provide any. But to see if record is duplicate of another record we should have a unique key anyway. so provide your table structure

Comment: I dont have to check if record is duplicate.. i've just to check if a column is empty..or even i can change the NOT NULL and set DEFAULT NULL, and then UPDATE to '//string' if it is not null or UPDATE to 'string' if it is NULL (which means that's the first INSERT into that column)

Answer (score 1):

If what you want is this:

first string:  column will contain 'firststring'

second string:  column will contain 'firststring//secondstring'

then do the update like this:

```
UPDATE tablename SET columnname = CONCAT( IF(IFNULL(columnname,'')='','',CONCAT(columnname,'//')), :string) WHERE username=:user
```