# MySQL: Update or Add if value isn't in DB

Tags: mysql

I'm attempting to write a mysql command that will either update an entry if X is in a value in the column, or insert the data as a new row if it isn't.

The problem is that it isn't a unique column - so DUPLICATE KEY won't work.

I've been trying to get it to work with IF's and CASE's to check is the result of a select for a value is `NULL`, but all to no avail.

It seems as though it shouldn't be that difficult - but I'm pretty newbish at writing SQL.

To reiterate I need to:
1. Update entry `col2` is `X` is in `col1`
2. OR Insert row is value already exists in col1.

Any insight is much appreciated.

EDIT - SOLVED: In spite of checking before posting, I realize now that the column is indeed unique, so I can use the proper DUPLICATE KEY function.

Comment: innodb table? do a `select for update` to lock the row if it exists. if exists, then do your update. if it doesn't, then you can just proceed on to an insert.

Comment: possible duplicate of [MYSQL - append or insert value into a column depending on whether it's empty or not](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30078230/mysql-append-or-insert-value-into-a-column-depending-on-whether-its-empty-or)

Comment: If it is not UNIQUE, how would you know which row to update?

Comment: Actually, I stand corrected - it is indeed unique (this is on a table in Wordpress). I checked, but must misunderstood what I was looking at for the moment. Alex - it's similar to a few posts now that I realize that the table column is indeed unique.

Comment: It would help if you provided some sample data, the table structure, and some of the queries you have tried.

Answer (score 0):

```
// Search if X is in COL 1
IF (SELECT count(*) FROM Table WHERE col1 = X) > 1 
THEN // UPDATE Table SET col2 = X WHERE col1 = X
ELSE // INSERT ROW
```

Sorry, but I don't remember well the MYSQL Syntax but this is the idea.

Some references.
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/comparison-operators.html
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/counting-rows.html

I hope this help you.